# How would I find the number of solutions to equation

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 20$ if $0\leq x_i\leq 5$

I know how to get the total amount without restrictions. $24C4 = 10 626$

But I'm not sure how I would do it if there's a restriction like this. Could someone explain how in a simple manner?

Comment: Please rewrite the question. As it stands, it's completely incomprehensible.

Comment: $x1+x2+x3+x4+x5$ is not an equation, so it does not have solutions.

Comment: I think he ask 'the number of pairs $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ satisfies that $x_i\ge 0$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,5$, $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_5\le 5$'.

Comment: Number of solutions of *what*? perhaps you mean "quantity of natural numbers that can be written as $x_1+\cdots+x_5$, with each $x_i\in\mathbb N$ and $x_i\leq 5"$. Your writing is awful.

Comment: Doug: Your number is the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)^5$. That is, 126.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler argument probably exists, but here is my idea: For $1\leq i\leq 5$ let $A_i=\{(x_1,\dots,x_5)\in\mathbb N^5: x_1+\cdots+x_5=20, x_i>5\}$. You want to calculate $c=|A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_5|$, which is the number of undesired solutions. From this you get your answer, namely $10626-c$.

In order to calculate $c$ we apply inclusion-exclusion principle: consider the number of solutions $(x_1,\dots,x_5)\in\mathbb N^5$ of $x_1+\cdots+x_5=20$ with $x_{i_1},\dots,x_{i_k}>5$, where $i_1,\dots, i_k$ are fixed and satisfy $1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k\leq 5$ (of course we must have $1\leq k\leq 5$). In other words, we are seeking for $|A_{i_1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{i_k}|$. Note that you can write $x_{i_\ell}=6+y_{i_\ell}$ with $y_{i_\ell}\in\mathbb N$, and $y_{i_\ell}$ *has no restriction*. Your equation becomes $6k+z_1+\cdots+z_5=20$, with $z_1,\dots,z_5\in\mathbb N$ without further restriction, that is solutions in $\mathbb N^5$ of $z_1+\cdots+z_5=20-6k$. There are $\dbinom{24-6k}{4}$ such solutions for each choice of indices $i_1,\dots, i_k$, which in turn can be made in $\dbinom5k$ ways. The number of solutions is obviously $0$ for $k=4,5$. Therefore, by inclusion-exclusion principle:

$$c=\sum_{k=1}^3(-1)^{k+1}\binom5k\binom{24-6k}4=\,\style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{do it by yourself!}}\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

number of solutions of equation $$x_1+x_2+...+x_s=m,0\leq x_i\leq s$$
is
$${\binom{m}{k}}_{s}=\sum_{i=0}^{m}(-1)^{i}\binom{m}{i}\binom{m+k-si-1}{m-1}\,$$ 
in this case $$m=20,s=5,k=5$$
$${\binom{20}{5}}_{5}=\sum_{i=0}^{5}(-1)^{i}\binom{20}{i}\binom{24-5i}{19}\,$$